# Eclipse CDT Debugger Console IO error

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I try to Debug an application using the Eclipse CDT, there seems to be a problem with input/output. New output only shows when `endl` is appended, while I still can't get the Console to accept any input. I am running Eclipse under Ubuntu. The IDE has just been updated. What could be wrong?

Comment: These both sound like 'features' of Eclipse to me. Not seeing any output until you flush (using endl for instance) is normal behaviour for a console. That you can't read from the console has always been a feature of Eclipse (though why is anyone's guess).

Comment: What do you mean by "features"? Isn't there any way to input data in Debug mode? No problem occurs when simply running the application... How could I debug a console program using Eclipse?

Comment: In this case by "feature" I mean limitation.

Comment: This mustn't be the case. In a simple application that reads and then displays the input, I actually get the feedback (in my case the Character that I input) when the debugging stops. In any other case, the process hangs upon when reaching a `cin`.

Comment: Is it a bug? Because throughout the Internet, they say that you simply have to type you input in the Console...

Comment: In the Eclipse help, they mention that the Console is both for output and input.